# If two graphs are planar, will the cartesian product between them be planar?

Tags: graph-theory

I think this question is false, but I am not sure how to prove it. I found the product of two 3-cycles (see diagram). But I don't know how to prove it can't be planar. It passes Euler's formula. I have tried looking for subgraphs that fail the test, but am not finding any.[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to make the diagram smaller.

Comment: I can find a subdivision of a $K_5$ in your graph.  Four of the edges are subdivided.  Remember that in [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem) we need not find a $K_5$ subgraph, merely a subdivision of a $K_5$ to conclude that it is not planar.

Comment: I wasn't taught Kuratowski's theorem. I'm not sure what a subdivision is. Is there a way to prove it without using this theorem?

Comment: A subdivision of a graph is a graph where some number of subdivisions have taken place: a new vertex $x$ is added and an edge $(u,v)$ is removed and replaced by two edges $(u,x)$ and $(x,v)$.  Think of it like taking an edge and drawing additional vertices along it.  What do you mean you weren't taught Kuratowski's theorem?  That is usually one of the very first things mentioned when talking about planar graphs.  Have you at least seen some direct proof that $K_5$ is not planar?

Comment: We did discuss $K_5$ not being planar because the number of edges, $10 \nleq 3(5)-6$.

Comment: You mention Euler's Formula.  You can reason that $K_5$ does not pass the criterion and therefore is not planar.  You can then reason that any graph which contains $K_5$ cannot be planar, and then any graph which contains a subdivision of $K_5$ cannot be planar.  This will then prove the result you want, and is a partial proof to Kuratowski's theorem.  The more difficult part of proving the theorem is that this is in fact an if and only if statement, that not only having a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ subdivision makes it nonplanar, but all non-planar graphs have a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.

Comment: The reason being, if a graph containing a subdivision of $K_5$ *were* planar, then using that drawing and removing unnecessary vertices and edges and contracting edges (*the reverse of the subdivision process*) would yield a planar drawing of $K_5$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70123/discussion-between-maggy-wood-and-jmoravitz).

Answer (score 5):

I can find a subdivision of a $K_5$ in your graph.  Four of the edges are subdivided.  Remember that in [Kuratowski's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem) we need not find a $K_5$ subgraph, merely a subdivision of a $K_5$ to conclude that it is not planar.  Labeling the vertices $a,b,c,\dots$ instead and removing unnecessary edges:

[image: A K-5 Subdivision]

As there is a $K_5$ subdivision as a subgraph, your original graph too therefore cannot be planar.

Answer (score 2):

Another counterexample is the hypercube $Q_{d}$ for $d \geq 4$. We note that $Q_{d} = \prod_{i=1}^{d} K_{2}$. In particular, $Q_{4} = Q_{3} \times K_{2}$, and both $Q_{3}, K_{2}$ are planar.

Answer (score 1):

If we take the Cartesian product of $K_4$ and $K_2$ (both planar), then by identifying the vertices in one of the copies of $K_4$, we get a $K_5$ minor.  [Wagner's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem) thus implies it's non-planar.

Another counterexample is the Cartesian product of $K_4$ and $K_4$.  It has $v=16$ vertices and $e=48$ edges, but this does not satisfy $e \leq 3v-6$, which is required by [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler's_formula) for planar graphs.